# R square change for 2-way interaction model

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I want to test a regression model with neuroticism as focal predictor, agreeableness as moderator and RT variability as dependent measure (covariates: attentional control and mean RT). Previously, I have used the modprobe macro in SPSS by Andrew Hayes for this (see: http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBRM.41.3.924). I am in the process of transitioning to R, however, and would like to learn how to run a similar routine there. I have set up my regression model as follows:

```
m3<-lm(data=stp2_sub2, all_SD~Neuroticism*Agreeableness+Attentional.Control+all_RT, na.action=na.omit) # full interaction model
m33<-lm(data=stp2_sub2, all_SD~Neuroticism+Agreeableness+Attentional.Control+all_RT, na.action=na.omit) # reduced model
```

I know that I can obtain F-change and p-change, using:

```
anova(m3, m33) # provides F-change and p-change
```

What I still don’t know yet is how to obtain the R squared change value, which gives me the effect size of the interaction effect. I have already posted a similar question at one of the sister websites ([Computing R-squared change, F-, and p-values for the interaction / moderation term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159299/computing-r-squared-change-f-and-p-values-for-the-interaction-moderation-te/159304?noredirect=1#)), although it seems that my question was slightly off-topic there. The users there have been very helpful (especially @gung), but I still have some remaining questions. Hence me posting here.

Basically, the recommendations have been so far to compute (a) semi-partial r-squared or (b) partial eta squared. For (a) semi-partial r-squared a custom-written function already exists (see: [Calculating effect size for variables in a multiple regression in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71816/calculating-effect-size-for-variables-in-a-multiple-regression-in-r/136615#136615)). Unfortunately I am a bit at a loss as to how to exactly adapt it to my own case, particularly the following bit: y = 4 + .5*x1 - .3*x2 + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1). Moreover, even if I did succeed at adapting y to my own needs, I would still need to know how to compute the r change value. The function for semi-partial r-squared yields a single r value (i.e. it doesn’t provide a change value, yet). In my case, would I need to, in a first step, run this function for (1) the full model (here: m3) as well as for (2) the reduced model (here: m33), thereby providing me with two semi-partial r-squared values (full vs. reduced)? In a second step, would I then subtract semi-partial r-squared (reduced) from semi-partial r-squared (full), with the outcome being the r-change value that I need?

As for b, I have been told to use the following « formula » ( SSE(reduced)-SSE(full) ) / SSE(reduced) to compute partial eta squared for the interaction effect. I have found code for computing the sum of squared errors (see: [How does anova.lm in R calculates "Sum Sq"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49924/how-does-anova-lm-in-r-calculates-sum-sq)) and have applied this to my case as follows:

```
SSEfull<-sum(m3$residuals^2) # sum of squared errors/residual sum of squares for the full regression model
SSEred<-sum(m33$residuals^2) # sum of squared errors/residual sum of squares for the reduced regression model

pes<-(SSEred-SSEfull)/SSEred # computing partial eta-squared
```

I would like to know whether I have correctly implemented the code to compute partial eta squared for the interaction effect. Moreover, given that I need the r squared change value, I was wondering how I might be able to convert the partial eta squared value to the r squared change value that I need. That said, as mentioned above, I just need to know how to compute the r squared change value for my interaction model. Ultimately, I don’t mind whether I do this following suggestions (a) or (b) (but note that I still have some questions in this regard) or use a completely different way. Indeed, perhaps there’s already a function/package in R that calculates the r change value (I haven’t found one yet)? I feel like being very close to finding what I need, but just need a final few pointers. Apologies for the long-winded way of writing this simple question, but I thought it could be of use to show what thought (even if not yet conclusive) has already gone into this. Any guidance on how to best go about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting question but perhaps more appropriate for the stats folks at CrossValidated.